# What is the best approach to producing graphical charts in a browser?

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, svg, charts

I've started a new open source project aimed at providing a quality project management experience.  To do this, I need access to a set of chart tools (Flash is off the table), and very specifically one that includes a Gantt chart.  I've done my homework and shopped around the web and I've more or less come to the conclusion that what I want doesn't exist, at least not for free.  So chances are I'm going to have to write this from scratch.

If I was going to create a Gantt chart with which people could interact with (which I'm assuming means having excellent DOM support), then what technology would I use?  Should I go with SVG?  Or HTML5 Canvas?  Something else?  Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Also, a requirement would be that whatever library I use needs to be actively supported in the community (i.e. no dead projects).

Comment: Are you doing something Six Sigma related?

Comment: What exactly is it about the existing systems that doesn't suit your needs? This is a huge undertaking, you'd probably be better off forking an existing project and hacking it to meet your needs.

Comment: @vol7ron: Nothing specific to Six Sigma, in fact I had to look that up because I did not know what that was :)

Comment: @Chris: The purpose of the project is more or less an exercise in learning new technology, as well as potentially providing myself with a tool specifically tailored to my needs.  I've always wanted to touch on SVG but have never really had the time or the reason to do so.  Now that I'm fresh out of college, I have a little more time on my hands, and thus I'm looking for a fun and challenging open source project to contribute to.

Comment: I've discovered something amazing.  If I had just searched GitHub like a proper Rails programmer then I would have found this https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView.  Pretty much the exact functionality I was looking for.  As per Chris's suggestion, I have forked the project and am now making it my own, and will contribute back once it's doing what I need it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to make your own, I'd recommend the SVG library [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), which allows you to draw things using SVG fairly easily. It's also simple to make mouse event handlers and other things, which you could use to make it interactive.

I haven't had much experience creating interactive graphics with `canvas`, but my instinct is that it would be hard to handle mouse events since you don't have "elements" to add event listeners to.

Comment: In the event https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView doesn't work out for me, I'll be rolling my own with Raphael.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not think there would be many free options as this is a niche-need.

#### JS Option:

- http://www.jsgantt.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/flot/

#### Promising Perl modules:

- http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DARNOLD/DBD-Chart-0.82/dbdchart.html
- [http://search.cpan.org/~awestholm/Project-Gantt-1.03/Gantt.pm](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eawestholm/Project-Gantt-1.03/Gantt.pm)

---

#### Update:

There's been amazing advancements in terms of interactive/web charts in the past few years.  Shortly before your question was asked, [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) was created, which has become a generally accepted library, which uses SVG to implement visualizations.  Here's a [basic example](http://dk8996.github.io/Gantt-Chart/) and a [more advanced](https://codepen.io/jey/details/jmClJ) implementation using `D3`.  Note; Gantt charting is still in its infancy; D3 will most likely revisit it in the future.

The argument of Canvas vs SVG is one that has been considered many times.  You should read this article by Microsoft; [How to Choose Between Canvas and SVG for your Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh552482.aspx).  Basically, if you have many elements you have to display, Canvas will perform much better.  If accessibility is a priority, SVG is better.

In terms of working with Canvas vs SVG, canvas feels more fluid and it is certainly more capable with WebGL, but SVG is more transportable.  They both have their merits.

Comment: I looked at jsGantt, however it seems like the project is dead in the water.  Flot looks like it could have some useful features, I may check that out, there is a lack of Gantt support though.  I won't be using Perl for this project, I will be using Rails, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: The project might be dead, but if it still works, why does it matter? Especially if you were going to roll your own